# With the Server-side model using the project template where can I place an api controller that is externally accessible?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

With a server-side Blazor for an intranet app, using the project template, where would one place api controllers?  In the .Client project or the .Server project?

In other words, I want an api that is within the same web app, accessible via a path like this  it-app.something-internal-route.net/api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your API into your Controller which is inside Server Assembly

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(<your result list / object>)
    }
}
```